# 'Grouping' hourly timeframes

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have used date_trunc to group my data by hour. From here, I want to get data from consecutive hours that fit my conditions.

For example, in 24 hours...

```
|   time   |  basket  |   item   |
|   00:00  |    A     |   apple  |
|   01:00  |    B     |   banana |
|   02:00  |    A     |   orange |
|   02:00  |    A     |   apple  |
|   03:00  |    B     |   grapes |
|   05:00  |    A     |   pear   |
|   08:00  |    A     |   apple  |
|   11:00  |    B     |   grapes |
|   15:00  |    A     |  cherries |
```

I want to find the maximum number of fruits that have been in any basket in 3 consecutive hours.
For example, basket A  has had an apple and orange in 3 consecutive hours (00:00 to 02:00)
So the result would look like:

```
|  basket  |   item   |
|    A     |     2    |
```

I want every basket's results in 3 consecutive hours included here as well. In my main data, there are many 'baskets' and many 'items', over months of data. How do I go about this?

I feel like the solution here is to use something like lag and lead or partition by, but neither of them seem to exactly solve my problem.

Comment: Does "time" indicating the beginning of an hourly group? Basket A doesn't have any data in the 01:00 time, so doesn't have three consecutive hours between 00:00 and 02:00.

Comment: @FlexYourData By 'consecutive hours' I mean counting from 00:00, the 3 hours that follow are considered the 'consecutive period' (0, 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0):

Create a full list of all timeslots and cross join with distinct baskets.

Left join with data and count distinct items in each timeslot/basket.

Tested on PostgreSQL, so I hope will be fine for Redshift.

```
DROP TABLE if exists your_table;

CREATE TABLE your_table 
(
  TIME TIMESTAMP,
  basket   VARCHAR(1),
  item     VARCHAR(8)
)
;

INSERT INTO your_table (time, basket, item) VALUES
  ('2023-05-12 00:00:00', 'A', 'apple'),
  ('2023-05-12 01:00:00', 'B', 'banana'),
  ('2023-05-12 02:00:00', 'A', 'orange'),
  ('2023-05-12 02:00:00', 'A', 'apple'),
  ('2023-05-12 03:00:00', 'B', 'grapes'),
  ('2023-05-12 05:00:00', 'A', 'pear'),
  ('2023-05-12 08:00:00', 'A', 'apple'),
  ('2023-05-12 11:00:00', 'B', 'grapes'),
  ('2023-05-12 15:00:00', 'A', 'cherries');



WITH boundaries AS
(
  SELECT start_time,
         start_time +INTERVAL '2 hours' AS end_time,
         basket
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_DATE+INTERVAL '23 hours','1 hour') start_time,
       (SELECT DISTINCT basket FROM your_table) AS baskets
)
SELECT x.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT y.item) AS items
FROM boundaries x
  LEFT JOIN your_table y
         ON y.time BETWEEN start_time
        AND end_time
        AND x.basket = y.basket
GROUP BY x.start_time,
         x.end_time,
         x.basket;
```

Obviously you will need to change the generate_series statement to reflect the start and end of your data.